# Variables not working... or i'm missing something?

Tags: python, variables, numbers, docx

I am trying to make some edits to a docx file... making a number into letter (i.e. if the variable is equal to 01 = 'one', equal to 02 = 'two', and so on, but in Spanish).  The problem is that the variable `f_dia_nom` doesn't work ... it doesn't even print anything... am I doing something wrong?? or am I missing something??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6

from Tkinter import *
from docx import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()

nombre = ""
exp_no = ""
ubic = ""
munic = ""
prov = ""
f_dia = ""
f_dia2 = ""
f_dia_nom = ""

def nombre_dia():
         if f_dia2 == 1 or f_dia2 == 01:        
             f_dia_nom = "Un"
         elif f_dia2 == 2 or f_dia2 == 02:               
             f_dia_nom  =  "Dos"
         elif f_dia2 == 3 or f_dia2 == 03:        
             f_dia_nom = "Tres"
         elif f_dia2 == 4 or f_dia2 == 04:               
             f_dia_nom = "Cuatro"
         elif f_dia2 == 5 or f_dia2 == 05:               
             f_dia_nom = "Cinco"
         elif f_dia2 == 6 or f_dia2 == 06:        
             f_dia_nom = "Seis"
         elif f_dia2 == 7 or f_dia2 == 07:               
             f_dia_nom = "Siete"             
         else:
             f_dia_nom = "Error"

# Hacer el docx      
def makedocx():
         if __name__ == '__main__':        
             # Default set of relationshipships - these are the minimum components of a document
             relationships = relationshiplist()

             # estructura del documento
             document = opendocx('test.docx')
             docbody = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body',namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]

             # Buscar y reemplazar
             print 'Replacing ...',
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_EXP',en1.get())            
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_NOMBRE',en0.get()) 
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_OPERACION',op.get())           
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_UBIC',en3.get())
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_MUNI',en4.get())
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_PROV',en5.get())
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_F_DIA',en6.get())
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_F_MES',mes.get())          
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_F_SEM',sem.get())
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_NUM_DIA',en7.get())            
             nombre_dia()
             docbody = replace(docbody,'V_NOM_DIA',f_dia_nom)            
             print 'f_dia_nom'
             print 'done.'
```

Comment: Is `makedocx` even being called?

Comment: This is just part of the code... the one with the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up 'global scoping' rules for python.  In general, try to avoid global variables as much as possible(if only to avoid errors like these)

in nombre_dia():

```
f_dia_nom = "Un"
```

or any other assignment for that matter has the python compiler create that number LOCAL to the nombre_dia function.

modify your function to declare f_dia_nom as a global:

```
def nombra_dia():
   global f_dia_nom

   ...
```

It will have nombre_dia SEE the f_dia_nom as the global

### References

Learning Python 4th edition pg 408

Comment: I'm glad.  However make sure you know _why_ it worked.  Understanding the nuances of scoping rules for a given language is a sure way to rise above noobdum(noobness?).

Answer (score 2):

`f_dia_nom` is a global variable, which is not really a great start. If you want to manipulate it, pass `f_dia2` to the function `nombre_dia()` as an argument and then return `f_dia_nom` from the function afterward.

```
def nombre_dia(f_dia2):
         if f_dia2 == 1 or f_dia2 == 01:        
             f_dia_nom = "Un"
         elif f_dia2 == 2 or f_dia2 == 02:               
             f_dia_nom  =  "Dos"
         elif f_dia2 == 3 or f_dia2 == 03:        
             f_dia_nom = "Tres"
         elif f_dia2 == 4 or f_dia2 == 04:               
             f_dia_nom = "Cuatro"
         elif f_dia2 == 5 or f_dia2 == 05:               
             f_dia_nom = "Cinco"
         elif f_dia2 == 6 or f_dia2 == 06:        
             f_dia_nom = "Seis"
         elif f_dia2 == 7 or f_dia2 == 07:               
             f_dia_nom = "Siete"             
         else:
             f_dia_nom = "Error"

         return f_dia_nom

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # All your other code...
    f_dia_nom = nombre_dia(f_dia2)
    print 'f_dia_nom =', f_dia_nom
    docbody = replace(docbody,'V_NOM_DIA',f_dia_nom)
    print 'done.'
```

Comment: Or use `global` *evil chuckle to match green-head avatar* (+1)

Comment: NEVER USE `global`! (Unless you can help it!)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `if __name__ == '__main__':` That is testing whether or not you are in the main module. (The one you specifically asked to run). I'm guessing that you aren't.

`if __name__ == '__main__'` only makes sense if you are on the module level (outside of any functions, so you can detect if you are being run or being imported.)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to see exactly what's supposed to be going on in your code, but a few points:

1. You're printing the string 'f_dia_nom' rather than the variable f_dia_nom
2. You can't change global variables from inside a function without using `global <variable>` first
3. No need to check against 1 and 01 (etc.) since 1 == 01
4. You don't seem to be setting/creating `f_dia2` anywhere...